# How can we use case in Select Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case

Is there any way to print the Column Conditionally in SQL? Lets say 
`Select FirstName, LastName, RollNumber, Subject, Marks From Student` gives the output of 5 Column `FirstName, LastName, RollNumber, Subject, Marks`. Also it accepts One parameter `@NameType`. If `@NameType = 'First'` then the output should be only `FirstName, RollNumber, Subject, Marks`. Similarly, If `@NameType = 'Second'` then the output should be only `SecondName, RollNumber, Subject, Marks` excluding Column `FirstName`. How Can this be Achieved?

```
Declare @NameType nvarchar(max);

Set @NameType='First'

Select FirstName, LastName, RollNumber, Subject, Marks From Student
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @NameType VARCHAR(10)
SET @NameType = 'First';

SELECT CASE WHEN @NameType = 'First' THEN FirstName
            WHEN @NameType = 'Second' THEN LastName END as [Name]
,RollNumber
,Subject
,Marks
FROM Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what your after is:

```
DECLARE @NameType varchar(6); --no reason to be a `MAX`, Second is only 6 characters long,
                              --and it doesn't need to be an nvarchar, as neither string contains unicode characters
SET @NameType = 'First';
SELECT CASE @NameType WHEN 'First' THEN FirstName
                      WHEN 'Second' THEN LastName
       END AS [Name],
       RollNumber,
       Subject,
       Marks
FROM Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
case when @NameType = 'First' then FirstName
     when @NameType = 'Second' then SecondName end ColName,
RollNumber, Subject, Marks From Student
```